# Prove relationships in momentum problem.

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

I'm working on a situation where an object $A$ in motion hits a stationary object $B$, and the two exchange momentum. **Object $A$ is drawn as a box for simplicity but is meant as something like an arrow** that can potentially pierce through object $B$, imparting some of its momentum, but still continuing past object $B$.

As in the illustration I made, and with what's said above, this can happen three different ways (There's a fourth but I'm not interested in it):

- (Scenario X) Object $A$ sticks to object $B$ and the two move together
- (Scenario Y) Object $A$ pierces through $B$
- (Scenario Z) Object $A$ hits object $B$ and recoils back (giving $A$ negative velocity and momentum)

[image]

Starting from conservation of momentum, one can set up equations that govern each scenario.

The question is: **holding all initial conditions constant, which scenario would impart the most final velocity, and therefore momentum, to object $B$?**

I know how to find this from a physics perspective, in a qualitative way. But for fun, I want to show myself the rigorous mathematical way of how this is true.

Most of it is very straightforward:

- Set up the momentum equations for each scenario
- Arrange each equation so it's solved for $B$'s final velocity $v_{bf}$
- Analyze all three expressions for this velocity to figure out the inequalities between them.

I completed the first two steps to yield:

- (Scenario X)   $$\frac{mv_{ai}}{m+M} = v_{bf}$$
- (Scenario Y)   $$\frac{m(v_{ai}-v_{af})}{M}= v_{bf}$$
- (Scenario Z)   $$\frac{m(v_{ai}+v_{af})}{M}= v_{bf}$$

The correct answer is:  $Z > X > Y $

And I can easily show that $Z > Y$ and $Z > X$ but can't figure out how to show $X > Y$ to finish the proof.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{mv_{ai}}{m+M}&>\frac{m\left(v_{ai}-v_{af}\right)}{M} \\ 
Mv_{ai}&>(m+M)\left(v_{ai}-v_{af}\right) \\ 
0&>mv_{ai} -(m+M)v_{af}
\end{align*}
The final inequality holds because $v_{af}>v_{bf}$ by virtue of object A piercing through object B, and so $(m+M)v_{af}$ is greater than the total momentum after the collision in scenario Y.